# how can I add context menu from app_commands

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to add context menu from app_commands, I tried that, but it didn't work

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands


@app_commands.context_menu(name="Hello")
    async def hello(interaction: discord.Interaction, message: discord.Message):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Hey !")
```

I'm using `discord.py 2.0.1`, how can I add?

Answer (score 2):

Context menu's are a bit tricky to get working, here's an example:

```py
async def hello(interaction: discord.Interaction, message: discord.Message):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hey {message.author.mention}!")

hello_context_menu = app_commands.ContextMenu(
    name='Say Hello',
    callback=hello,
)
bot.tree.add_command(hello_context_menu)
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't come to apps section, can you edit it as full code you tried?

Comment: Are you syncing your bot commands? This would require syncing with the guild

Comment: no i can't sync, can you edit it as full code

Comment: To sync your app commands @yusufkuşçu the easiest way to do it is in your bot's on_ready function: add `bot.tree.sync()`

Comment: To add to my prior comment, I've discovered it would be better to do it in the `setup_hook()` Bot/client event instead of `on_ready`, as on_ready will be triggered multiple times in the lifecycle of your bot, whereas setup_hook only runs once. If you are loading and unloading commands/cogs whilst the bot is running then it would be a good idea to add a regular message command (e.g. `@commands.command()`) that will run `bot.tree.sync()` so you have a way to re-sync app commands and context menus etc. without restarting the entire bot

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's been 11 months, but I was also looking for this answer. I came up with this:

```py
@app_commands.context_menu(name="Test context menu")
async def test_context(interaction: discord.Interaction, user: discord.User):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Test context menu", ephemeral=True)

bot.tree.add_command(test_context)
```

Just as was described before, remember to sync the tree